# Sequentially compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies $A$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, compactness

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a sequentially compact set. I want to prove that $A$ is a bounded set.

Since $A$ is sequentially compact, for every sequence $(x_k)\subset A$, there exists a convergent subsequence $x_{k(p)}\subset (x_k)$ which converges to some point $b\in A$. Since $x_{k(p)}$ is convergent, it is bounded, so that $\exists M>0$ such that $\|x_{k(p)}\|\le M$.

Now, I think the idea is to show that the sequence $(x_k)$ must thus also be bounded. I think this can be achieved by proving that if we suppose that $(x_k)$ is unbounded then $(x_{k(p)})$ cannot be bounded. But I do not quite see how to prove this.

My reasoning is that there should probably be some maximum distance between the closest $x_k$ and $x_{k(p)}$, which should indicate that the distance is always finite. But how do I show that?

Comment: If $A$ is unbounded, there's a sequence in $A$ with $|x_n|\to\infty$.

Comment: As an aside, know that an important result in topology is that a metric space $X$ is compact $\iff$ it is sequentially compact $\iff$ it is limit point compact.  In metric spaces, we also have compact $\iff$ closed & bounded.  These equivalences break down as we peel away different axioms like metrizability or Hausdorffness, and seeing which axioms are responsible for what additional structure is of particular interest.

Comment: In the case that $A \subset \mathbb {R}$, take, for example, $(x_n) = 1$ if $n$ is even, and $(x_n) = n $ if $n$ is odd. $(x_{2n}) $ is a bounded, convergent subsequence, but $(x_{2n-1}) $ is unbounded, and therefore so is $(x_n) $

Comment: W.r.t. your idea, we can conclude that $(x_n$) is bounded (because otherwise it would has a subseq. converging to $\infty$ and this subseq. would be a sequence in $A$ without a convergent subseq.). However, this **does not solve the problem** unless you show that the bound you get for $(x_n)$ does not depend on the sequence. In other words, to make your idea work you also need to show that the same bound holds for any sequence (you could prove it by contradiction but it would be the same as assuming $A$ unbounded). So, I think the better way is as explained in the other comments and answers.

Comment: Oh crap, I meant to write "in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we also have compact $\iff$ closed and bounded" above.  This *is not true* for general metric spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is unbounded, so that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $x_n\in A$ such that $\vert\vert x_n\vert\vert > n$. Can you show that the sequence $(x_n)$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Do you think the following is correct / rigorous? Suppose $(x_{k(p)})$ is a convergent subsequence of $x_k$. Then $(x_{k(p)})$ is bounded, i.e. $\exists M>0$ such that $\|x_{k(p)}\|\le M$. Let $p_0$ be such that $k(p_0)>M$, then $\|x_{k(p)}\|> k(p)> M$, a contradiction.